# How to check the value of a bit in C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitset

I would like to check the value of the 5th and the 4th bit starting from the left in this strings like this one:

```
value: "00001101100000000000000001000110"

value: "00000101100000000000000001000110" 

value: "00010101100000000000000001000110"
```

The value is generated as a string in this way:

```
        msg.value = bitset<32>(packet.status()).to_string();
```

to be sent a a ROS node and I receive it as a string.
Can I still use bitset to check the value of the bits even if it is a string?
What is the best solution to check them?

Comment: It is difficult to say which of many possible solutions is best in your situation. Generally, I would separate the data representation in transmission from data processing, i.e. have an internal representation (e.g. bitset) and a method for encoding/decoding to/from the transmission representation (e.g. string). Any processing of data should be done on the internal representation. This way, the interface and inner logic are separated so one can be changed with minimal impact to the other. However, as said, it all depends on the situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a `bitset`, you have a `string`, in which each "bit" is represented by a `char`.

To check the 4th and 5th "bits", just use:

1. `msg.value[3] != '0'` and `msg.value[4] != '0'`
2. `msg.value[3] & 1` and `msg.value[4] & 1`

#2 might be faster; it exploits the fact that `'0'` and `'1'` differ in the lowest bit only.

Answer (score 1):

Just create the bitset on its own, do the tests and then make a string out of it. (Or recreate a bitset from the string and test on that)

```
#include <bitset>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct msg_t
{
    std::string value;
};

struct packet_t
{
    std::string status()
    {
        return "00001101100000000000000001000110";
    }
};

int main()
{
    packet_t packet;
    auto bits = std::bitset<32>(packet.status());
    bool bit4 = bits.test(4);
    bool bit5 = bits.test(5);

    if (bit4) std::cout << "bit 4 is set\n";
    if (bit5) std::cout << "bit 5 is set\n";

    msg_t msg;
    msg.value = bits.to_string();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP asks to check the values of 4th and 5th bit starting from the left in the string. If my understanding is correct, this answer checks the values of the 4th and 5th bit from the right in the string (and counting from 0 - it is unclear if OP is counting from 0 or 1).

Comment: I agree it was unclear as there is no real standard for bit counting. Anyway it would not be too hard to correct for that (either 31-4, or 32-4 depening on start counting at 0 or 1)

Comment: Right, it is just important to be aware of it. Btw, in light of my comment to the question, I think this is the best answer.